# Ошибка Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, laravel

Делаю блог по видео урокам , но вот почему то выдает такую ошибку. Не могу решить, помогите, пожалуйста. Вроде всё как надо , пробовал уже и такую запись

create.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app_admin')

@section('content')

<div class="container">

  @component('admin.components.breadcrumb')
    @slot('title') Создание категории @endslot
    @slot('parent') Главная @endslot
    @slot('active') Категории @endslot
  @endcomponent

  <hr />

  <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('admin.category.store')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    {{-- Form include --}}
    @include('admin.categories.partials.form')

  </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

form-blade.php

```
   <label for="">Статус</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="published">

  @if (isset($category[0]->id))
    <option value="0" @if ($category->published == 0) selected="" @endif>Не опубликовано</option>
    <option value="1" @if ($category->published == 1) selected="" @endif>Опубликовано</option>
  @else
    <option value="0">Не опубликовано</option>
    <option value="1">Опубликовано</option>
  @endif
</select>

<label for="">Наименование</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок категории" value="{{$category->title or ""}}" required>

<label for="">Slug</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="slug" placeholder="Автоматическая генерация" value="{{$category->slug or ""}}" readonly="">

<label for="">Родительская категория</label>
<select class="form-control" name="parent_id">
  <option value="0">-- без родительской категории --</option>
  @include('admin.categories.partials.categories', ['categories' => $categories])
</select>

<hr />

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
```

categories.blade.php

```
@foreach ($categories as $category_list)

  <option value="{{$category_list->id or ""}}"

    @isset($category->id)

      @if ($category->parent_id == $category_list->id)
        selected=""
      @endif

      @if ($category->id == $category_list->id)
        hidden=""
      @endif

    @endisset

    >
    {!! $delimiter or "" !!}{{$category_list->title or ""}}
  </option>

  @if (count($category_list->children) > 0)

    @include('admin.categories.partials.categories', [
      'categories' => $category_list->children,
      'delimiter'  => ' - ' . $delimiter
    ])

  @endif
@endforeach
```

"Undefined offset: 0 (View: D:\wamp\www\blog\resources\views\admin\categories\create.blade.php)"
CategoryController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use  App\category; // use your app namespace
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.categories.index',[
            'categories' => category::paginate(10)
        ]);
    }



       /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
      public function create()
    {
       return view('admin.categories.create', [
          'category'   => [],
          'categories' => category::with('children')->where('parent_id', '0')->get(),
          'delimiter'  => ''
       ]);
    }
      public function store(Request $request)
{
   category::create($request->all());
   return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
}
```

Comment: Ошибка наверняка встречается в _конкретной строке конкретного файла_. Мало кто настолько мазохист, чтобы в уме прокручивать сотню строк кода на предмет "где может встретиться ошибка ХХХ?" Хотите конкретной помощи - дайте конкретную и полную информацию по ошибке, выделите строку кода, в которой ошибка встретилась, (чтобы по всей портянке не искать, особенно когда нумерация строк в приведенном коде отличается от нумерации строк в исходном файле). Учитесь ценить чужое время.

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko "Undefined offset: 0 (View: D:\wamp\www\blog\resources\views\admin\categories\create.blade.php)"

 это то что мне выдают

Comment: На других страницах, где `@extends('admin.layouts.app_admin')` есть, ошибка тоже вылетает?

Comment: нету , на других нет . только на этой единственной http://localhost/blog/public/admin/category/create

Comment: form.blade.php: `@if (isset($category[0]->id))`. Замените на `@if (isset($category[0]) && isset($category[0]->id))`.

Comment: Вы в form.blade.php не передаёте ничего. Там не может появиться переменная $category

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko не помогло

Comment: @ArtemKostrikov и как пофиксить? Очень плохо понимаю пока что

Comment: Какую переменную Вы с контроллера передаёте?

Comment: `@include('admin.categories.partials.form')` => `@include('admin.categories.partials.form', ['category'] => "некий массив объектов, в котором есть элемент с индексом 0")`

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko а categories.blade.php этого не делает ?

Comment: У Вас нужно весь код исправлять. Я сейчас к сожалению с телефона комментирую, поэтому не могу привести пример. Но если Вы с контроллера передаёте $categories тогда эту переменную нужно передавать дальше по иерархии шаблонов и в когда бежите циклом по массиву то $category_list не может быть $category.

Comment: @ArtemKostrikov  оооочень тяжело

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views

Comment: Я логику не проверял у Вас. @ArtemKostrikov прав. Вам стоит проследить логику передачи аргументов во вставляемые sub-views.

Comment: Если бы я хотя бы что то понимал . Я не могу быстро сообразить и с этими подключениями файлов и с их содержимым. Просто неожиданный поворот событии сегодня был с этим Laravel.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос метод контроллера, который вызывает эти view. Попробую помочь.

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko Добавил categrorycontroller , пожалуйста , помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create.blade.php

```php
@extends('admin.layouts.app_admin')

@section('content')

<div class="container">

  @component('admin.components.breadcrumb')
    @slot('title') Создание категории @endslot
    @slot('parent') Главная @endslot
    @slot('active') Категории @endslot
  @endcomponent

  <hr />

  <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('admin.category.store')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    {{-- Form include --}}
    @include('admin.categories.partials.form',
            ['category'   => $category,
             'categories' => $categories,
             'delimiter'  => $delimiter])

  </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

form.blade.php

```php
<label for="published">Статус</label>
<select id="published" class="form-control" name="published">

@if (isset($category) && isset($category->id))
    <option value="0" {{ ($category->published == 0) ? 'selected' : '' }}>Не опубликовано</option>
    <option value="1" {{ ($category->published == 1) ? 'selected' : '' }}>Опубликовано</option>
@else
    <option value="0" selected disabled>Не опубликовано</option>
    <option value="1" disabled>Опубликовано</option>
@endif
</select>

<label for="title">Наименование</label>
<input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок категории" value="{{ $category ? $category->title : '' }}" required>

<label for="slug">Slug</label>
<input id="slug" class="form-control" type="text" name="slug" placeholder="Автоматическая генерация" value="{{ $category ? $category->slug : '' }}" readonly />

<label for="parent_id">Родительская категория</label>
<select id="parent_id" class="form-control" name="parent_id">
  <option value="0">-- без родительской категории --</option>
  @include('admin.categories.partials.categories', 
          ['categories' => $categories,
           'current' => $category,
           'delimiter' => $delimiter])
</select>

<hr />

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
```

categories.blade.php

```php
@foreach ($categories as $category)

  <option value="{{ $category->id ?? '' }}" 
   {{ ($current && isset($current->parent_id) && $current->parent_id === $category->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}
   {{ ($current && isset($current->id) && $current->id === $category->id) ? 'hidden' : '' }}>
    {!! $delimiter ?? '' !!}{{ $category->title ?? '' }}
  </option>

  @if (isset($category->children) && is_array($category->children) && count($category->children) > 0)

    @include('admin.categories.partials.categories', [
      'categories' => $category->children,
      'delimiter'  => ' - ' . $delimiter,
      'current'    => $current
    ])

  @endif
@endforeach
```

CategoryController

```php
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.categories.create', [
       'category'   => null,
       'categories' => category::with('children')->where('parent_id', '0')->get(),
       'delimiter'  => ''
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас с телефона. Проверить не могу, но как только так сразу . Надеюсь заработает , если нет, то я пропал. Я отпишу

Comment: Спасибо большое . Сработало

Comment: Так это Вы что, тестовое задание для устройства на работу сюда сунули?.. :(

Comment: эммммммм делаю курсачь . Хочу сделать новостной портал , но на ларавел. А так как его сдавать через недели две , а я работаю и учусь , я не успеваю , делал по видео , но не понимал почему у меня ошибка. Пришлось бы всё что сделал переделывать по других урокам , а времени нет , а решить проблему сам не мог

Comment: Могу только посоветовать потратить пару часов и _внимательно_ изучить документацию по Laravel. Особенно - примеры в ней. Оченно способствует пониманию того, что и как можно сделать стандартными средствами без напряга. Сам осваивал Лару именно по примерам в доке. Чуть дольше чем по видеоурокам, но в голове все устаканивается стройнее и знаешь где посмотреть пример. Видеоурок - примерный план действий, после него - полное изучение всех разделов доки, которые в этом уроке затрагиваются. Без первоисточника все равно не обойтись.

Comment: Я вас понял ))))